# How to push an artefact to maven.pkg.github.com?

Tags: maven, github, pom.xml

How to push an artefact / Jar to maven.pkg.github.com ? Let's say I have a maven project, and I want to build and push this artefact to github package repository.

Comment: Have you read the docs: https://github.com/features/packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

full documentation provided below link

[Maven for use with GitHub Packages](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-packages-with-github-packages/configuring-apache-maven-for-use-with-github-packages#authenticating-to-github-packages)

to summarize:

generate a new personal access token from the github settings

add repository and token info in your settings.xml

deploy using

```
mvn deploy -Dregistry=https://maven.pkg.github.com/yourusername -Dtoken=yor_token
```